# Searching Site Farm / Collections for instance of URL

Tags: powershell, migration, sharepoint-enterprise, xml

I am looking into a way to search for a specific URL within SharePoint. I have seen the solution that searches with [PowerShell script for searching lists for specific links?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19223/powershell-script-for-searching-lists-for-specific-links) and http://blog.henryong.com/2011/05/20/sharepoint-link-reporter-using-powershell/ but I need something a bit in between.

The last solution would be great, if I could just filter its results into to display just the urls that contain a specific URL (for examples, lets just call it sample.test.com). Is  it possible to modify the line `$customLinkObjects | Select-Object WebTitle,WebURL,TopNavLink,TopLinkTitle,TopLinkURL,QLHeaderTitle,QLHeaderLink,QLChildLinkTitle,QLChildLink,ListName,ItemTitle,ItemURL,PageContentLink | Export-Csv $filePath` to filter out the results unless the result is equal to sample.test.com ?

Or if there is a more elegant solution, please let me know. I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible you just need to come up with the script.
Se the following samples:

http://blog.henryong.com/2009/02/11/purging-a-sharepoint-list-using-powershell/

http://sharepointnomad.wordpress.com/2009/12/30/create-and-delete-sharepoint-list-views-with-powershell/

http://blogs.flexnetconsult.co.uk/colinbyrne/2008/02/26/PowerShellSharePointThreeWaysToDeleteAListItemIDCAMLStringMatching.aspx
Cheers

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link is broken, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)